# Count punctuation in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, punctuation

I'm trying to count punctuation in the `content` column of this DataFrame. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865048/counting-punctuation-in-a-given-text) and it doesn't work. My DataFrame looks like this:

[image: this]

I want the result to be like this:
[image: this] 
but instead of emotions to count the punctuation of every article.

```
In:

text_words = df.content.str.split()
punctuation_count = {}
punctuation_count[','] = 0
punctuation_count[';'] = 0
punctuation_count["'"] = 0
punctuation_count['-'] = 0

def search_for_single_quotes(word):
    single_quote = "'"
    search_char_index = word.find(single_quote)
    search_char_count = word.count(single_quote)
    if search_char_index == -1 and search_char_count != 1:
        return
    index_before = search_char_index - 1
    index_after = search_char_index + 1

    if index_before >= 0 and word[index_before].isalpha() and index_after == len(word) - 1 and word[index_after].isalpha():
        punctuation_count[single_quote] += 1

for word in text_words:
    for search_char in [',', ';']:
        search_char_count = word.count(search_char)
        punctuation_count[search_char] += search_char_count
    search_for_single_quotes(word)
    search_for_hyphens(word)

Out:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Punctuation of what? The values within the columns or the publication itself?

Comment: punctuation of the column content

Comment: Please start by posting what you have tried that is specific to your problem, not just linking to a similar example. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried the exact same thing as at the linked post and I've got this error:    'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['I love, pizza, hamberget and chips!!.', 'I like drink beer,, cofee and water!.'], columns=['content'])

                                content
0   I love, pizza, hamberget and chips!!.
1   I like drink beer,, cofee and water!.
```

Try this code:

```
count = lambda l1,l2: sum([1 for x in l1 if x in l2])

df['count_punct'] = df.content.apply(lambda s: count(s, string.punctuation))
```

and gives:

```
                                 content  count_punct
0  I love, pizza, hamberget and chips!!.            5
1  I like drink beer,, cofee and water!.            4
```

If you want to accumulate the punctuation marks of each line in a list:

```
accumulate = lambda l1,l2: [x for x in l1 if x in l2]

df['acc_punct_list'] = df.content.apply(lambda s: accumulate(s, string.punctuation))
```

and gives:

```
                                 content  count_punct   acc_punct_list
0  I love, pizza, hamberget and chips!!.            5  [,, ,, !, !, .]
1  I like drink beer,, cofee and water!.            4     [,, ,, !, .]
```

If you want to accumulate the punctuation marks of each line in a dict and transpose each element into dataframe columns:

```
df['acc_punct_dict'] = df.content.apply(lambda s: {k:v for k, v in Counter(s).items() if k in string.punctuation})

                                 content            acc_punct_dict
0  I love, pizza, hamberget and chips!!.  {',': 2, '!': 2, '.': 1}
1  I like drink beer,, cofee and water!.  {',': 2, '!': 1, '.': 1}
```

now expanding the dictionary in the columns of the df:

```
df_punct = df.acc_punct_dict.apply(pd.Series)

   ,  !  .
0  2  2  1
1  2  1  1
```

If you want to combine the new dataframe with the starting one, you just need to do:

```
df_res = pd.concat([df, df_punct], axis=1)
```

and gives:

```
                                 content            acc_punct_dict  ,  !  .
0  I love, pizza, hamberget and chips!!.  {',': 2, '!': 2, '.': 1}  2  2  1
1  I like drink beer,, cofee and water!.  {',': 2, '!': 1, '.': 1}  2  1  1
```

**Note**: If you don't care about the column with the dictionary you can delete it by `df_res.drop('acc_punct_dict', axis=1)`

Comment: I've already tried something similar and it works. However, I am trying to display each punctuation mark individually instead of getting a sum of all of them in the text. e.g. !: 3, ?: 1, etc. I would really appreciate it if you could show me something similar

Comment: @KaterinaKass I updated the answer, let me know if that's what you were looking for

Comment: Check out this link. This is the result I was hoping for                https://ibb.co/8jyZTxG

Comment: @KaterinaKass Ok now I understand what you have to do, I updated the answer. Let me know if you have any doubts. If my answer was helpful, please vote up it and accept it. Thanks